# Overriding tag and equation

Tags: ieeetran, overlays

My code and result are like the followings:

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{cl}
\label{prob}
    \minimize_{\bx_{1}, \bx_2, \ldots, \bx_n}
    & \quad f(\bx_1, \bx_2, \ldots, \bx_n, \bm{y})\IEEEyesnumber\\
    \subjto
    & \quad\cdots,\IEEEyessubnumber*\\
    & \quad\cdots,\\
    & \quad \max_{k=1,\ldots,\lvert\bx_v\rvert-1} g(\bx_v(k), \bx_v(k+1)) \le h(\bm{y}), \forall v \in \mathcal{S},\\
    & \quad\cdots,
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
```

[image: img]

The third constraint equation overrides the tag (6c).
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can kill the tag with `\notag` or `\IEEEnonumber` and then add a blank line that is numbered:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{cl}
\label{prob}
    \mbox{minimize}_{\mathbf{x}_{1}, \mathbf{x}_2, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_n}
    & \quad f(\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_n, \mathbf{y})\IEEEyesnumber\\
    \mbox{subject to}
    & \quad\cdots,\IEEEyessubnumber*\\
    & \quad\cdots,\\
    & \quad \max_{k=1,\ldots,\lvert\mathbf{x}_v\rvert-1}
    g(\mathbf{x}_v(k), \mathbf{x}_v(k+1)) \le h(\mathbf{y}), \forall v
    \in \mathcal{S}, \IEEEnonumber\\
    &\\
    & \quad\cdots,
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{document}
```

To decrease the vertical space before the tag, you can write e.g. `\IEEEnonumber\\[-1.5ex]`.   Alternatively use `amsmath` environments, such as `aligned`, that will shift the tag automatically as needed

In more extreme case you would have to break your condition over several lines, but you could still use `\notag` or `\IEEEnonumber` to suppress the numbering.

Comment: For some environments like {equation}, the tag is automatically written "a little bit" below the equation when there is no space for the tag (right of the equqation).
However, if I use \notag here, the tag is exactly written in the next line, so it looks bad. :(

Comment: @Danny_Kim -- the `IEEEarray` environment should really take care of such details (as the `amsmath` environments do but the basic latex `eqnarray` does not).  but since it doesn't, your best bet for improving the appearance of this situation is to use the optional `[-nnn]` after the `\\ ` in the line from which the number was removed, to close up the space.